# Подключение по https в Delphi, WinXP

Tags: delphi, rest, https, google-drive

Использую в Delphi REST Client для работы с Google Drive API, все отлично работает если сеть идет напрямую, без прокси, а если есть прокси то подключение не проходит. На работе локальная сеть, инет идет через прокси 192.168.0.16:8080 который прописан в свойствах обозревателя, программа просто не загружает страницу OAuth авторизации гугла, возможно проблема в том что порт для https 443 а в прокси 8080? как подключаться к 443 порту? Подскажите что нибудь

Все это под XP, под win 7-8 все работает

Думаю ошибка во встроенном TWebBrowser, ведь именно он используется для отображения формы авторизации по OAuth2.0

```
LURL := 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth';
LURL := LURL + '?response_type=' + URIEncode('code');
LURL := LURL + '&client_id=' + URIEncode(clid);
LURL := LURL + '&redirect_uri=' + URIEncode('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
LURL := LURL + '&scope=' + URIEncode('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');

wv := Tfrm_OAuthWebForm.Create(self);
try
wv.OnTitleChanged := self.OAuth2_GoogleDrive_BrowserTitleChanged;
wv.ShowModalWithURL(LURL);
finally
wv.Release;
end;
```

wv-встроенная форма REST клиента с TWebBrowser.

Данный кусок кода по видимому не отрабатывает, скорее всего зависает на
    wv.ShowModalWithURL(LURL) (обращение к URL выше)
и ничего не отображается

Comment: Какая версия Internet Explorer установлена ?
Какой прокси-сервер используется?

Comment: В Internet Explorer этот адрес открывается?

Comment: Скорее всего 6 или 7 версия, в нем не пробовал открыть. Но настройки прокси одинаковы и в Win7 и WinXP. Из ответа ниже понял что зависание именно из-за свойства Silent в wv.Browser, хотя не понятно почему только в XP зависает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предполагаю, что у вас включено свойство "Silent" в элементе управления WebBrowser. В результате блокируется диаологовое окно прокси.

Подробнее:

- [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151109032616/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/04/side-effects-of-setting-the-silent-scripterrorssuppressed-property-for-web-browser-control.aspx)

Comment: Спасибо, действительно это свойство было включено, проверю завтра результат, но уверен, что проблема именно в этом, т.к. другие программы иногда запрашивают доступ

Comment: @SimFd: Будем ждать результатов завтрашних экспериментов!

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что страница `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth` в IE 6 выдает ошибку javascript
[image: screenshot 2015-04-07 001.png]

Но выключение `silent` никак не поможет, кнопка "Принять" не нажимается.
Нужно обновить IE хотя бы до 8 версии, либо авторизоваться через другой браузер

Comment: направлять в другой браузер я уже пробовал, все работает, только нужно копировать код, вот если бы он сам это делал... попробую с TChromium

Comment: Как вариант, если авторизовывать в другом браузере, можно в своем приложении поднимать простой http сервер на некотором порту, и передавать гуглу `redirect_uri` такой `http://localhost:порт/`
(гугл это точно поддерживает 
http://goo.gl/LOuXV2).
Но конечно через компонент Chromium будет проще, но и весит он немало.

Comment: уже переделал под EmbeddedWB, Chromium не нашел для XE7

Comment: Так EmbeddedWB тоже на Internet Explorer основан вроде?

Comment: процесса IE в диспетчере нет, и ошибок скриптов не выходит, не знаю, нужно проверить

Comment: При использовании движка IE никакого процесса не создается.

Comment: ага, проверил, с EmWB тоже самое, не активна кнопка Принять и Отмена, в общем сделал проверку на версию браузера, если выше 6 то запускать обычную авторизацию, если 6 и ниже то направлять в браузер и ждать ввода ключа в InputBox

Comment: Я проверил в IE Tester, в IE версии 7 тоже не работает.
Значит минимальная версия - восьмая.

Comment: под виртуалкой в 7 версии проверил - страница прогружается, но кнопки также не активны. Видимо просто перенаправлять будет не очень правильно, IE 7 под ХР еще довольно распространен